# My Code in not running in Eclipse TesNg test

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, testng

```
package com.policybazaar.testcases;

    import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

    import com.policybazaar.pages.Healthpage;
    import com.policybazaar.pages.Loginpage;

    /**
     * @author Anshita
     * 
     */

    public class VerifyPbLogin {

        AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;

        @BeforeClass
        public void launch() throws MalformedURLException {

            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "EBAZFG240031");
            capabilities.setCapability("version", "4.4.2");
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.policybazaar");
            capabilities.setCapability("app_activity",
                    "com.policybazaar.ui.activity.SplashScreenActivity");
            driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(
                    "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }

        public void verifylogin() {

            Loginpage login = new Loginpage(driver);
            login.LoginToPb("9899998890");

        }

        public void healthquotes() throws InterruptedException {

            Healthpage quotes = new Healthpage(driver);

            quotes.healthjrny("anshta test", "test@test.com", "Delhi (Delhi)");

        }

CONSOLE RESPONSE

package com.policybazaar.testcases;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

import com.policybazaar.pages.Healthpage;
import com.policybazaar.pages.Loginpage;

/**
 * @author Anshita
 * 
 */

public class VerifyPbLogin {

    AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void launch() throws MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "EBAZFG240031");
        capabilities.setCapability("version", "4.4.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.policybazaar");
        capabilities.setCapability("app_activity",
                "com.policybazaar.ui.activity.SplashScreenActivity");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(
                "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
```

I have written my code to run my login activity of my native android app  but when I'm running my below code using TestNG it does not get executed and I get below response in console:

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.9.9 [TestNG] Running:
>   C:\Users\anshita\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1997002605\testng-customsuite.xml
>
> ===============================================
>       Default test
>
> ## Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

[screen with set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsBxA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You atually do not have any methods annotated with `@Test`.
You only defined set-up methods with `@BeforeClass`.

Add at least one `@Test` method, otherwise the suite will think there is nothing to run.

Also i would suggest placing your sources in `src/main/java` and test sources in `src/test/java` as a good practice.